# Which character was "The Contaminated Man" in "Day the World Ended"?

Tags: character-identification, day-the-world-ended-1955

The movie credits list Paul Dubov as Radek, who if you watch the movie is the early-stage mutant they allow they stay in the house, despite strong sentiment that he should be killed. There is also a character played by Jonathan Haze (I believe the last surviving actor from this 65-year-old film who was also in Corman's *Little Shop of Horrors*) called "The Contaminated Man", but there don't seem to be enough roles to go around -- the only idea I have is that two different actors played the same role at different stages, or The Contaminated Man was cut from the movie. Certainly Radek was contaminated by radiation, and Haze seems to resemble Radek more than the picture of Dubov does.

Comment: Your edit is not appropriate for being in the question itself but would make some sense as a comment on the answer. I've commented to you this before but this is not a discussion forum so please stop editing your questions like this and treating the site as one.

Comment: I disagree -- this is an explanation as to why the confusion occurred. You make me want to discontinue contributing by this edit.

Comment: Of course it’s an explanation for why the confusion occurred but if you knew why you wouldn’t be asking the question so it doesn’t make sense as an edit to the question. Posting it as a comment on the answer is perfectly fine though so I suggest you do that. I don’t mean to put you off from posting but you still need to fit with the format and rules of the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](https://scifist.wordpress.com/2017/02/08/day-the-world-ended/), Jonathan Haze played this character.

[image]

For reference, here's another picture of Haze from [his Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Haze).

[image]

He appears in only one scene in the film ([which is up on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZteUB5rDjZ4)), about halfway through the runtime, weakly speaks a few lines of dialogue, and then dies. He was never referred to by name, which I imagine is why the credits merely list him as "The Contaminated Man".

Radek is clearly a separate character in the film, who is referred to by name, and is still alive after the scene in question.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, my Vulcan friend. I have seen the movie many times but somehow missed the guy who dies. Radek is the mutant who chats about radiation-related stuff. It seems to me that Haze in the scene from Little Shop resembles Radek quite a bit but they are different people.